# Ubuntu 20.04 Network Manager Wireguard DNS Leak

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, wireguard

I added my Peer-Config from Wireguard to Network Manager manually:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.5
PrivateKey = key
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 10.13.13.1, lan

[Peer]
PublicKey = key
Endpoint = domainname:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

I  get a successfull connection from wireguard. But I found out, that the DNS from Wireguard is not used. I get a DNS-Leak.

When I check the status from wg0. I get:

```
Link 14 (wg0)
      Current Scopes: DNS       
DefaultRoute setting: yes       
       LLMNR setting: yes       
MulticastDNS setting: no        
  DNSOverTLS setting: no        
      DNSSEC setting: no        
    DNSSEC supported: no        
  Current DNS Server: 10.13.13.1
         DNS Servers: 10.13.13.1
          DNS Domain: lan
```

Wlan has:

```
Link 2 (wlp59s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 172.20.10.1
         DNS Servers: 172.20.10.1
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

And when I check my DNS requests via dnsleaktest.com I see that my Ubuntu uses the DNS from WLan and not from the wireguard. I read about to change the DNS Domain from Wireguard to "~."

When I make the change then I get a result that my ubuntu uses both DNS requests from Wlan and Wireguard. But I could not find any solutions to use only the DNS over Wireguard.

I read from a post from 2019 that this was a bug in Network Manager from Ubuntu. We are now in 2022 and is this bug still there?

One more info:
When I use the same config over my Phone I have no DNS-Leaks.

Comment: I see a Winegaurd question here with nothing to do with Ubuntu. Maybe ask them?

Comment: I found that this Issue is discussed directly in the gitlab from NetworkManager. The Issue is not yet done. The Issue comes from NetworkManager and not from Wireguard

Source: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/921

Comment: issue 921 was a bug in a recent version of NetworkManager. It is already fixed, it's not likely that you are using the version (although you don't specify).

Comment: My NetworkManager is in Version 1.22.10.

Answer (score 2):

check `ipv4.dns-priority` and `ipv6.dns-priority`. Those need to be set to a negative value (e.g. `-50`), if you want to avoid DNS leaks. Read `man nm-settings`.

You can see the setting with `nmcli connection show "$PROFILE"`. You get the `$PROFILE` name from `nmcli connection`. You can change the DNS priority with `nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" ipv4.dns-priority -50 ipv6.dns-priority -50`.

As always, when you modify a profile that is currently active, then the changes only take effect after (re)activating the profile the next time (or doing `nmcli device reapply`). That means, do an `nmcli connection up "$PROFILE"` afterwards.

Comment: Hi thaller, thanks for your answer! I tried it and have still the DNS-Leak. And when I write the last step 'nmcli connection up $PROFILE, then the priority goes back to 0. and with priority of -50 I have still the DNS-Leak :(